# Can not debug C++ code in Visual Studio 2019 ("Source Not Available"/"Unable to start program: *.exe" issues)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, access-denied

I am using Windows 7 Professional.

I am trying to debug a simple C code in a C++ project in Visual Studio 2019. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("#########################################\n");
    // n: day that the query stops
    int n = 5;
    printf("Day to stop receiving queries: %d\n", n);
    // q is the number of queries received by day
    // ql is the amount of queries left to the next day
    // k is the max of queries replied by day
    long long int q = 0, ql = 0, k = 250;
    printf("Max queries to read per day: %lld\n", k);
    // day is the current day
    int day = 1;
    while (1) {
        printf("#########################################\n");
        if (day > n) {
            q = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("Enter the number of queries received today\n");
            scanf("%lld", &q);
        }
        printf("Day: %d\nQueries received today: %lld\nTotal of queries to read today: %lld\n", day, q, (ql + q));
        if ((q + ql) > k) {
            ql = q + ql - k;
            printf("q: %lld\n", q);
            printf("ql: %lld\n", ql);
            printf("k: %lld\n", k);
        }
        else {
            ql = 0;
            break;
        }
        printf("Left queries to the next day: %lld\n", ql);
        day++;
    }
    printf("#########################################\n");
    printf("#########################################\n");
    printf("Day with free time: %d\n", day);
    printf("#########################################\n");
    printf("#########################################\n");
    return 0;
}
```

1. If I try to debug with x64 option, I get the "Source Not Available" message:

["Source Not Available" message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqn5S.png)

I have put a break point at the beginning of the code and notice it throws an exception at the line "scanf("%lld", &q);". Here is the exception information: "*Exception thrown at 0x0000000076E6756E (ntdll.dll) in ChefAndEasyQueries.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.*"

2. If I try to debug with x86 option, I get the "Unable to start program *.exe / Access is denied" error message (it is in Portuguese):

["Unable to start program" message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHmu8.png)

The .exe file is not in specified directory. I do not know if the Visual Studio is not creating the file or if my PC is somehow deleting it.

Comment: I think you want to switch the Thread in this case to the MainThread.

Comment: Why are you using Windows 7 in 2020?

Comment: Your code is crashing, and where it crashes is in library code that you do not have the source for. This is most likely due to the parameters you pass to `scanf`.

Comment: ***I can't find .exe the file in the specified directory. I don't know if the Visual Studio is not creating the file or if my PC is somehow deleting it.*** Try disabling your antivirus.

Comment: Dai: "Why are you using Windows 7 in 2020?". It is a company PC. It is not my choice to use Windows 7.

Comment: Have you looked at the output during the x86 build? Any errors?

Comment: drescherjm - thanks for your tip. I think the antivirus is causing the problem. The *.exe is being deleted if I build and try to manually run it.

Comment: crashmstr. I checked the output and there is no errors. I also tried to run the same code in another PC and it runs ok. So I really think the issue is related to the antivirus I have installed in this PC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think my antivirus is deleting the *.exe file. I don't have privileges to stop or uninstall the antivirus so I will not be able to fix the issue in this PC.